# apache fop fails to generate pdf with latest jre update (java 8 update 73)

Tags: asp.net, apache, apache-fop

With Java 7 update xx, pdf was generated in my asp.net application. When I updated the Java version to latest , ie Java 8 Update 73 , its fails to generate pdf. No idea on whats the issue.
Tried other updates of Jre 8 , always fails, but works with jre 7 update xx

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm having a relatively similar issue, being we just updated to Java 8_73 and now the PDF generation is suddenly not working.

Answer (score 0):

Baji, while yo're doing things differently, e.g. ASP.Net and IIS instead of tomcat but still using Java 8 this article seems to indicate he got it working with Java 8 and Tomcat.  I know it doesnt answer your question 100%, but if the questions just on Java 8 support it looks like it works.

[An indicator FOP works with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578796/apache-fop-return-code-1-on-pdf-generation)